# How to set a time range in sleep and asyncio sleep with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, time, sleep

Somehow I can't find this on google how to set a time range in with sleep instead of a fixed time. I want to learn how to set a time range with `await asyncio.sleep(xxx)` and `time.sleep(xxx)`

I want to sleep between 100 and 10000 seconds. Is this possible only using sleep? If not how to do that

Comment: _I can't find this on google_ It's like the first google page on "random delay python" search